# How do I get protractor to click my button? I keep getting an element is not visible

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have the following markup, and I am trying to access the `<button />`

```
<ul class="flower-list">
  <li ng-repeat="flower in model.flowers">
    <img ng-src="flower.imgUrl">
    <button ng-click="model.addToFlowerPot(flower)">Add</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following:

```
var flower = element.all(by.repeater('flower in model.flower')).first();
var addButton = flower.element(by.buttonText("Add"));
addButton.click();
```

Comment: check if there is a delay if the data is coming from service and wait until you get the data browser.waitForAngular(); that can be something that can cause issues

Comment: thanks that was the issue :(  appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if there is a delay if the data is coming from service. You can wait until you get the data with

`browser.waitForAngular()`

Answer (score 1):

`browser.waitForAngular()` is not the ideal way of handling such cases. Protractor waits for angular event loop internally. `Expected Conditions` should be used in these scenarios.

```
 var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 var flower = element.all(by.repeater('flower in model.flower')).first();
 var addButton = flower.element(by.buttonText("Add"));
 browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(addButton), 5000); //wait for the button to become visible in dom
 addButton.click();
```

or use promises directly which ever works :

```
  var flower = element.all(by.repeater('flower in model.flower')).first();
  flower.then(function() {
  return flower.element(by.buttonText("Add")).click();
  });
```

Comment: So whats faster? I think that would cause tests to run very slow if you are always waiting for few seconds here and there?

Comment: Only for that specific element we are waiting rather than the whole page with `browser.waitForAngular` it would be much faster!

Comment: is there a way to not set the time limit but just wait for element to be visible ? seems like a hack to hardcode the number of seconds, for example I have a production server that is much faster than my local environment so wouldn't want to wait 5 seconds if I don't have to :)

Comment: yes absolutely, in these cases we could write our own `expected conditions`. since these are promises we are talking about. we can use them, I update my answer pls check! you can also have a look at http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Comment: @vodich I agree with igniteram.  Also it's important to note that the timeout from `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(addButton), 5000);` is the _maximum_ amount of time to wait, not a guaranteed amount of time to wait.  So if the `addButton` element becomes visible in one second, it will fire off after one second instead of waiting for the declared five seconds.  But if it's not visible within 5 seconds (or whatever time you specify), then it fails.

Comment: Expected conditions are a safe way of assuring test stability across multiple environments (elements taking longer to load in production vs locally etc)

Comment: ah I get it, didn't know that is max time but not waiting every time. Cool info , thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `flower.then` is needed in this case? Rather `element.all(by.repeater('flower in model.flower')).first().element(by.buttonText("Add")).click();`. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe its not needed in this case, but could be handy sometimes!